# Zabbix strange behavior, can't access web interface

Tags: nginx, zabbix

So recently i tried to access my zabbix web interface as usual (before it i played with my site nginx config, but reverted it back), but now on entering URL and pressing enter i only get some strange file downloaded without name, file extenstion with only 50~ bytes of data in it, any suggestions?
[image]

Here is the file contents, but of course it's not human readable and doesn't make any sense

UPD: i tried URL like /index.php and now it downloads same file but with name index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in nginx config of the SITE (not the zabbix nginx config), `listen 80 http2;` had to remove http2